# How to convert data having multiple rows for same user into one row in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have data like this

| Id | Date | A header | BMI | Weight | Height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 08-11-2021 | David | 21.3 | 56 | 162 |
| 1 | 16-11-2021 | David | 21.3 | 56 | 162 |
| 1 | 17-11-2021 | David | 21.3 | 56 | 162 |
| 2 | 08-11-2021 | Lisa | 21.3 | 56 | 162 |
| 2 | 16-11-2021 | Lisa | 21.3 | 56 | 162 |

And I want O/P like this

| Id | Name | Date | BMI | Weight | Height | Date-2 | BMI | Weight | Height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | David | 08-11-2021 | 22.3 | 56 | 162 | 16-11-2021 | 21.3 | 56 | 162 |
| 2 | Lisa | 08-11-2021 | 20 | 50 | 105 | 16-11-2021 | 20.2 | 53 | 105 |

I'm not able to convert it into same row as required. I tried pivot, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Use pandas' `groupby` method `on` Name and choose how to group (mean / median / sum / count ...). Also, please don't post pictures, post the data as code so the problem is easily reproducable.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you also demonstrate that you are working to solve your issue. The best way to do that in my opinion is to include the text based version of the source code you have so far, even if it is not working quite right.

Comment: Please [edit] this question to type the text from the image so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.